# Cannot ungzip : Minimum header length is 10 bytes

Tags: linux, gzip

I have a problem with my website, which is completely gzipped:

```
http://goout.cz/cs/fotoreporty/
```

The page can be easily shown in Chrome, but in Safari it never loads (and I suppose in other browsers as well. When I try:

```
curl -v http://goout.cz/cs/fotoreporty/ | gzip -d
```

I am getting expected results. But validation on

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fgoout.cz%2Fcs%2Ffotoreporty%2F#fatal-errors

yields:

```
The error was: Can't gunzip content: Header Error: Minimum header size is 10 bytes
```

What is wrong with the gzip format? How can I solve it? Thanks.

EDIT:

The gzip header seems to me okay to me:

```
$ curl http://goout.cz/cs/ | head -1 | hexdump | head -1
0000000 1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ed 5d cd 73 db 38

$ curl http://goout.cz/cs/fotoreporty/ | head -1 | hexdump | head -1
0000000 1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ed 7d cf 73 e3 46
```

Comment: In firefox 23.0.1 it seems to work perfect.

Comment: Hm, now it loads even for me, but the validation still fails.

Comment: Loads fine in Chrome, Safari, Firefox.  Must be a bug in validator.w3.org.  You should report it to them.

Comment: I don’t think it’s a validator bug. The error message is rare, and googling with it gave [a forum post](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?808747-Blank-pages-in-Safari-and-IE-only-in-some-areas) (with no useful answer) about some browsers showing blank page, in addition to validator issue. I’m pretty sure the message refers to **gzip header**, which is at a level different than HTTP headers. The gzip specification, [RFC 1952](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1952), seems to require a “member header” that is at least 10 bytes.

Comment: I checked the gzip header, as you can see in my post and the header seems to be okay - the first ten bytes are valid.